# How do I implement a percentage chance function in a class object in C++?

Tags: c++

I have a homework assignment that requires me to calculate a percentage chance from an user input of the numbers 1 to 3. However, I'm not sure how to do this. 
This is my code, not all of it though:

```
void SwingAtBall( Ball *tBall ) {

std::cout << "How hard do you want to hit the ball? Please enter a number between 1 to 3." << std::endl;

    int tBallHit;
    std::cin >> tBallHit;
    if ( tBallHit > 3 || tBallHit < 1 ) {
        std::cout << "That is not a valid value. Please enter a number between 1 to 3." << std::endl;
        std::cin >> tBallHit;
    }


}
// Prompt for 1 to 3.  There is a (input * 15) percent chance the ball only goes 5 feet.  Otherwise the ball is hit a random number between 0 and (input * 150).  Print how far it went.
```

Comment: could you please elaborate your problem ?

Answer (score 0):

If my understanding is correct that there is an (input * 15) percent chance the ball will go 5 feet and an (100 - (input * 15)) percent chance it will go anywhere from 0 to (input * 150) feet, then the following code will calculate what you are looking for...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

int main()
{       

    int inp, chance1, dist1, dist2, dist_final;

    do {
        cout << "Enter integer between 1 and 3: ";
        cin >> inp;
    } while (inp < 0 || inp > 3);

    dist1 = 5;

    srand(time(0));
    dist2 = rand() % (inp * 150);

    chance1 = (inp * 15) / 100;

    dist_final = chance1 * dist1 + (1 - chance1) * dist2;

    cout << "It went this far: " << dist_final << endl;

    // system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: moving the `using namespace std` inside the main is better

Answer (score 0):

There's a whole [`<random>` header](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) for things like this.

Simple percentages are easy, you can use integers for that. Pick either 0-99 or 1-100, and use that in a [`uniform_int_distribution`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution). Sure, 15% is 3/20 so you could also use a `uniform_int_distribution(1,20)` but that's more obscure.

"0 to (input * 150)" is a `uniform_int_distribution(0,input*150)`.